# How Crop image with fengyuanchen/cropper and save in database the path of image crop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, crop

I'm trying to upload an image to a temporary folder for editing (crop)
image and create an avatar with the selected, but not working.

The button load should charge the image, once loaded should be displayed in:

but it does not. I'm doing wrong.

Note: if the image is static, if it works. but I need upload with button for make dinamic.

from there, I intent generate a preview of the selection of the image with cropper.
for see the result end of selected

after I get the values of the cropper intent create a new json format, to send and save the data in the database.

but I do not get !. someone can guide me!.

I have not worked with these technologies, 
so it is, I not understand how upload. and save in database the path and the image crop!.

Note: the image crop,  will be stored in a folder,  the original is not stored, it is only necessary to crop!.

thanks for your suggestions!.

this is the plugin: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

that, better than pediar helps people experienced in these technologies,
Thank you for your help !.

This is my code!.
------ Perhaps this bad my code, so I need, that  guide me, or show me, how to do or should do. thanks ----------

---

### Start the code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TEST DEMO UPLOAD</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery is required -->
        <link  href="css/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link  href="css/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link  href="css/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="javascript/cropper.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .img-container img {
            width: 400px;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="img-container">
        <img id="My_Image" alt="Picture Uploaded, To Crop" class="cropper" src="#">
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="previews ">
                <div class="img-preview preview-lg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        the cropper JQuery info: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper 
    <p>Example Upload and Crop with Cropper JQuery Plugins And Previews </p>
    <form id="form" action="Demomode.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <lobel>Select image a Upload:</lobel>
            <input type="file" id="Upload" name="Up" >
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
    <div>
        <label id="image-data"></label>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
    <script>

    // make references to file to charge in temp folder for edit with cropper    
    $('#Upload').click(function (){
          var cp = $('#My_Image > img').cropper({
          preview: ".img-preview", // A jQuery selector string, add extra elements to show preview.
          aspectRatio:4/4,
          strict:true,
          background:false,
          guides:false,
          autoCropArea:0.6,
          rotatable:false,
          crop: function(data){

          //create the preview of image original
                $('.img-preview').cropper({
                  preview: ".img-preview",
                  aspectRatio:1/1,
                  strict:true,
                  });

              //get data of part crop and send in format json for send to database
              if(data.height < 100 || data.width < 100){
              }else{
                  var json = [
                      '{"x":' + data.x,
                      '"y":' + data.y,
                      '"height":' + data.height,
                      '"width":' + data.width + '}'
                  ].join();
                  $().val(json);
              }

              // Send data of the image crop for save in database
                       $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data:json,
                        cache:false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log("success");
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function(data){
                            console.log("error");
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                        });

          }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above that sends the JSON object to the database only sends the coordinates of the cropper component so that PHP on the server side would do the actual cropping of the image. That's how this whole thing works.

So, if I were you, I would take a look at

http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-with-Canvas-CSS3-SimpleCropper.html

Their plugin is much easier. Initialize. Send Base64 to Server. Convert at Server Side. Viola!

Comment: solution should be focussed on existing plugin